# Trying to create a Map of Tiles in sfml using a vector

Tags: c++, sfml

How do I create a vector of Sprites using SFML and vector header?
I started the vector like

```
vector<sf::Sprite> test;
```

and I'm trying to do a push_back(), but I don't know what I need to put inside the "()".

Anyway, my vector will be 41x31, so there is a way t do something like

`vector<vector<sf::Sprite> > test (41,vector<sf::Sprite>(31,??))` 
?

I'm using this to create a tile map, if someone has a better idea, I will appreciate

EDIT:

I still got errors, thats my code

```
vector<vector<int> > mapc (5,vector<int>(5,1));

sf::Sprite mapa[5][5];

void fmap() {
    mapc[0][0] = 1; mapc[0][1] = 1; mapc[0][2] = 1; mapc[0][3] = 1; mapc[0][4] = 1;
    mapc[1][0] = 1; mapc[1][1] = 0; mapc[1][2] = 0; mapc[1][3] = 0; mapc[1][4] = 1;
    mapc[2][0] = 1; mapc[2][1] = 0; mapc[2][2] = 1; mapc[2][3] = 0; mapc[2][4] = 1;
    mapc[3][0] = 1; mapc[3][1] = 0; mapc[3][2] = 0; mapc[3][3] = 0; mapc[3][4] = 1;
    mapc[4][0] = 1; mapc[4][1] = 1; mapc[4][2] = 1; mapc[4][3] = 1; mapc[4][4] = 1;

    sf::Image w;
    w.LoadFromFile("w.png");
    sf::Image f;
    f.LoadFromFile("f.png");
    unsigned int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<mapc.size();i++) {
        for(j=0;j<mapc[i].size();j++) {
            if(mapc[i][j] == 1) { sf::Sprite teste(w); }
            else { sf::Sprite teste(f); }
           mapa[i][j] = teste;
        }
    }
//     test.push_back(teste);
}
```

it says that

"'teste' was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Actually I lied, if you know the exact size of the map then you can just use

```
sf::Sprite map[41][31];
```

Unless your map is going to be changing its size during runtime you should just create an array on the stack.

```
sf::Sprite temp; //used to initialize the map
map = new sf::Sprite[num_rows];  
for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){  
    map[i] = new sf::Sprite[num_cols];  
    for(int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++){  
        map[i][j] = temp;  
    }  
}
```

Then you'll want to run through the map one more time to initialize it.  If you can't do that and you need to use a vector then you can do something similar for the vector.

```
sf::Sprite temp; //used to initialize the map  
vector<vector<sf::Sprite> > map;  
vector<sf::Sprite> row;  
map.resize(0);  
row.resize(0);  
for(int i = 0; i < num_cols; i++){  
    row.push_back(temp);  
}  
for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){  
    map.push_back(row);  
}
```

Your map is then accessible as
    map[x][y]
in either case.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to just create a Sprite and put it in the vector.

```
 sf::Sprite sprite;
 test.push_back(sprite);
```

Easy peasy!

A `std::vector` resizes by itself, so you shouldn't need to worry about sizing.